# How can this lambda be rewritten with a guard clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the following lambda, gathered from the `README` of `Resque::Mailer` (https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer):

```
  Resque::Mailer.error_handler = lambda { |mailer, _message, error, action, args|
    # Necessary to re-enqueue jobs that receive the SIGTERM signal
    if error.is_a?(Resque::TermException)
      Resque.enqueue(mailer, action, *args)
    else
      raise error
    end
  }
```

Unfortunately, `rubocop` enabled on the codebase, complains about the `if..else` nature of the method, with the error: `Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression`.

I tried setting up an `unless` here, but so far, the `raise error` would be executed no matter which order I set it up. What's the right way to use a guard clause here?

To wit, the reason I ask this is, the following example seems to indicate that if I do the obvious thing with `unless`, the error will always be raised. Am I understanding this wrong?

```
Development [10] (main)> class Foo
Development [10] (main)*   def bar
Development [10] (main)*     puts "Outside unless getting exec" unless 1 == 2
Development [10] (main)*     puts "After unless getting exec"
Development [10] (main)*   end  
Development [10] (main)* end  
:bar
Development [11] (main)> Foo.new.bar
Outside unless getting exec
After unless getting exec
nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the condition into an `unless` should work, and satisfy `rubocop`:

```
 Resque::Mailer.error_handler = lambda { |mailer, _message, error, action, args|
    # Necessary to re-enqueue jobs that receive the SIGTERM signal
    raise error unless error.is_a?(Resque::TermException)
    Resque.enqueue(mailer, action, *args)
  }
```

Comment: I had actually tried executing some [example code](http://pastebin.com/aG7Hxd8f) which seemed to indicate that if I do this, the error will always be raised. Could you clarify?

Comment: That is not entirely correct - the error will be raised only if it is a `Resque::TermException`.

Comment: Okay, updated my question as well - could you explain why the `puts` appears to behave differently then?

Comment: The `raise` call will immediately raise an error, stopping the rest of the method from running. Your sample code calls `puts`, which doesn't stop execution, so both puts execute.

Comment: Right, so `raise` is something like `return puts "text"` if such a thing existed... thanks!